# SQL запрос на вывод данных

Tags: sql, ajax, joomla

Задача поставлена такая, что мне нужно при помощи SQL создать запрос, чтобы на моем web интерфейсе был вывод данных определенного значения, а так как я никогда с sql запросами не сталкивалась, для меня это темный лес.

Как можно это реализовать? Или хотя бы, дорогие знатоки, посоветуйте почитать какую-нибудь литературу, но с более-менее примерами, похожими на мою проблему, потому что вывод таблиц с магазинами, зарплатами и все в таком духе не подходят. Спасибо огромное за помощь.

Comment: а в чём проблема то? :-)

Comment: Проблема в том, что я даже и не знаю, как составить этот запрос правильно, прочитав несколько статей в интернете, не поняла ничего, поэтому и решила спросить, вдруг блондинке на пальцах объяснят, в каком русле думать и с чего начать)

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно. Невозможно ответить на вопрос "помогите, ваще ничо неполучаеццо(("

Comment: @Annetik вы бы хотя бы обрисовали язык с помощью которого генерится веб морда и SQL сервер к которому надо обращаться. Если это PHP+MySQL это одно, а если Java+SQL то другое. Технологии то везде разные (хотя суть одна и та же)

Comment: Эта веб морда написана на Ajax и полностью работает на sql запросах, а так как я последние 8 лет занимаюсь только Joomla, но иногда и на xml маленькие кодики писала, для меня это сложновато к пониманию, и sql запросы никогда не писала, а сервер MySQl.

Comment: Ну, думаю, можно начать с такого пошлого ресурса, как википедия.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

Comment: Если mysql, то потрясающий набор гайдов "для чайников". [link][1]. Очень простые и понятные минималистические статьи.


  [1]: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:
Python Flask PostgrSQL

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте или купите книгу "Руководство по MySQL" Авторы: Сейед Тахагхогхи, Хью Е. Вильямс есть PDF. Там очень подробно рассказывается про запросы к БД.

Но из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно как будете осуществлять вопросы к БД.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за совет по литературе, если честно, я сама не представляю, как обращаться к базе данных, но надеюсь, изучив литературу, смогу с этим вопросом разобраться.